# Probablity of hitting a square touching the inside of the bull's eye

Tags: probability

[image]

[image]

Here, X and Y are independent N(0,1).

Can someone explains to me how do we get (sqrt(2))/2 using rotational symmetry?

I do understand why r = sqrt(2ln(2)), but I do not understand the rotational symmetry part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did the logarithms get in there?

Comment: Because the P(shots inside the bull's eye) = 0.5 and then by using F(r)=1-e^(r^2 /2)=1/2, the r obtained is sqrt(2ln(2))

Comment: Aha. Am I missing where it says that the probability for hitting the bull's eye is $\frac12$? Or did you forget to state this in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we just look at the figure as shown, it is bounded by the lines
$\lvert X + Y\rvert = r$ and $\lvert X - Y\rvert = r,$
and *not* by the lines 
$\lvert X \rvert = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}r$ 
and $\lvert Y\rvert = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}r.$

But we can rotate the square by $45$ degrees and then it *is* bounded by
$\lvert X \rvert = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}r$ 
and $\lvert Y\rvert = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}r.$

Because of the rotational symmetry of the distribution, we know that the rotation did not affect the probability.

Comment: How do we get the (sqrt(2))/2? Does it have to do with the r?

Comment: $r$ is half the diagonal of the square, but when we put the square so its sides are parallel to the axes, the maximum $x$ coordinate is only half the _side_ of the square. The side is $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ times as long as the diagonal. Another way to see it: draw the square with sides parallel to the axes, centered at the origin. Draw a diagonal segment from the origin to a vertex of the square. Label the length of that segment: it is $r.$ Find the coordinates of the vertex.